# Using Django Allauth without allauth urls?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-allauth

I want to use django allauth package without its built in urlpatterns. Main reason for that is that I want to have the ulrs in different language. Also I dont want to have the allauth url available even if there is no redirectons to those pages in my site. Main reason I started to use allauth was the social login but I noticed that the regural account logic was nice and fast to implement. Is it neccesary to include allauth url to project if you want to use only the views and forms functionality? Or is there a better way to do it?

I have made custom views and forms all of the views and forms that I use but they all inherit allauth views and forms. I have also custom ulrs to all those views.
Example of my custom view:

```
class LogInView(AllAuthLoginView):
    template_name = 'accounts/log_in.html'
    form_class = SignInForm
```

I have tested that it works well when allaut urls are included. But if exlude allauth url I get this error when loading login page:
`Reverse for 'account_signup' not found. 'account_signup' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` 
I noticed that it comes from this function in allauth LoginView class:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ret = super(LoginView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        signup_url = passthrough_next_redirect_url(
            self.request, reverse("account_signup"), self.redirect_field_name
        )
        redirect_field_value = get_request_param(self.request, self.redirect_field_name)
        site = get_current_site(self.request)

        ret.update(
            {
                "signup_url": signup_url,
                "site": site,
                "redirect_field_name": self.redirect_field_name,
                "redirect_field_value": redirect_field_value,
            }
        )
        return ret
```

Even if name my signup view with "account_signup" it wont work.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('mylogin/',  LogInView.as_view(), name='account_login'),
    path('mylogout/', LogOutView.as_view(), name='account_logout'),
    path('mysignup/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='account_signup'),
```

If I try to override the "get_context_data" function in my view so that is does not do anything, I get this error: `Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form.`

This is my login page form in html:

```
      <form method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% bootstrap_form form label_class="text-white" %}
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Kirjaudu</button>
      </form>
```

I also have my own templates and emails.